# I can't run my jquery code as tools

Tags: jquery, css

I want to use [this](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html) jquery library for my web page. I am copying all the code in the article page and then pasting into my .html file as below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("document").ready(function(){
                $("#demo img[title]").tooltip();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <br />
    <br />
        <div id="demo">
          <img src="image1.jpg" title="The tooltip text #1"/>
          <img src="image2.jpg" title="The tooltip text #2"/>
          <img src="image3.jpg" title="The tooltip text #3"/>
          <img src="image4.jpg" title="The tooltip text #4"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But .tooltip class style is not running. I can't see the background image and others.
How do I need to edit my .html file?

Also if I want to change this library's css styles how can I?

Comment: have you added link to css file....?

Comment: where is the css file in http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html

Comment: there's demo.css, check the file's source

Comment: @paiCode I can see titles but without css styles

Comment: You also need to include jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/QWeKw/2/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/XUhxQ/

You can make your own styling.

Very good link: http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/ **or** http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip

This should help,

**code**

```
$("img[title]").tooltip({
    events: {
        def:     "mouseenter,mouseleave",    // default show/hide events for an element
        input:   "focus,blur",               // for all input elements
        widget:  "focus click,blur",  // select, checkbox, radio, button
        tooltip: "mouseenter,mouseleave"     // the tooltip element
    }
});
```

**css inside demo**

```
.tooltip {
    font-family:tahoma;
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px;
}​
```

**Working image**

[image]                      ​

Comment: @Birlikisgu lol yes you can use the css in (http://www.jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html), I was just giving you a extra info if you know more about plugin and stuff `:)` see the **working demo /code** you will see what was wrong, have a nice one!

Answer (score 1):

Well for the demo, add this style inside you **head** tag:

```
<style>

      .tooltip {
        display:none;
        background:transparent url(http://jquerytools.org/media/img/tooltip/black_arrow.png);
        font-size:12px;
        height:70px;
        width:160px;
        padding:25px;
        color:#eee;
      }
        /* style the trigger elements */
      #demo img {
        border:0;
        cursor:pointer;
        margin:0 1px;
      }
</style>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<style>
  .tooltip {
    background-image:url(http://jquerytools.org/media/img/tooltip/black_arrow.gif);
  }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score -1):

If you put `alert("HI");` in your javascript, does it appear?

Also, `<!doctype html>` should be at the top.

For CSS, put this in head: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />`

Comment: Just create an empty file. You could start by adding: `body { background-color: pink; }`, for example